# anonymous delegates in C#

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

I can't be the only one getting tired of defining and naming a delegate for just a single call to something that requires a delegate. For example, I wanted to call .Refresh() in a form from possibly other threads, so I wrote this code:

```
private void RefreshForm()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(new InvokeDelegate(Refresh));
    else
        Refresh();
}
```

I'm not even sure I have to, I just read enough to be scared that it won't work at some later stage.
InvokeDelegate is actually declared in another file, but do I *really* need an entire delegate dedicated just for this? aren't there any generic delegates at all?
I mean, for example, there's a Pen class, but there's also Pens.*pen-of-choice* so you don't have to remake the whole thing. It's not the same, but I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: There's no such thing as "anonymous delegates" in C#. There are delegates (like what you are using) and anonymous methods (which are only accessible through a delegate).

Comment: I guess since the C# spec uses the term "anonymous method" that it would be the correct way.  However, this term is used by a lot of people to mean a delegate instantiated with an anonymous method as a parameter.  So, they mean the same thing, but the context in which someone might use one term over the other depends often on whether or not there is a delegate assignment occurring or if the anonymous method is being passed directly to another method.  I welcome any arguments to the contrary.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes.  In .NET 3.5 you can use [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) and [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) delegates.  The Func delegates return a value, while Action delegates return void.  Here is what the type names would look like:

```
System.Func<TReturn> // (no arg, with return value)
System.Func<T, TReturn> // (1 arg, with return value)
System.Func<T1, T2, TReturn> // (2 arg, with return value)
System.Func<T1, T2, T3, TReturn> // (3 arg, with return value)
System.Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TReturn> // (4 arg, with return value)

System.Action // (no arg, no return value)
System.Action<T> // (1 arg, no return value)
System.Action<T1, T2> // (2 arg, no return value)
System.Action<T1, T2, T3> // (3 arg, no return value)
System.Action<T1, T2, T3, T4> // (4 arg, no return value)
```

I don't know why they stopped at 4 args each, but it has always been enough for me.

Comment: 4 is not a concrete rule, but past that you should at least consider combining parameters in some way.

Comment: When I'm porting some older .NET code to 3.5 and I see a delegate I swap them out for either Func or Action.

Comment: The next version of the framework will include Func and Action of more than four parameters.

Answer (score 26):

There's the Action delegate you could use, like so:

```
private void RefreshForm()
{
    if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(new Action(Refresh));
    else Refresh();
}
```

Or, with lambda syntax:

```
private void RefreshForm()
{
    if (InvokeRequired) Invoke((Action)(() => Refresh()));
    else Refresh();
}
```

Finally there's anonymous delegate syntax:

```
private void RefreshForm()
{
    if (InvokeRequired) Invoke((Action)(delegate { Refresh(); }));
    else Refresh();
}
```

Comment: oddly, the second and third syntaxes do not work saying it cannot convert it to System.Delegate because it is not a delegate type. However, Action is most definitely what I want.

Comment: anonymous delegates can't be passed this way to Invoke because they are not of Type Delegate.  What you wrote here doesn't even compile.

Comment: Heh, that's what I get for not checking before posting. I'll fix asap.

Comment: oh also, isn't using Action the best practice? I mean, most efficient in space and time etc?

Comment: Casting the lambda and anonymous delegates to Action does the trick. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In your case, yes, I would use Action - which is why I supplied it first.

Comment: this was a very helpful post.

Answer (score 8):

In this specific case you can (and should) just use [MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) to do this...  that is why it exists.

```
if (InvokeRequired)
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Refresh));
else
    Refresh();
```

If you were doing something else you could, as others have answered use Func<T,...> or Action<T,...> if they fit your use case.

Comment: This is the best solution for .NET 2.0

Answer (score 5):

Short version:

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Refresh(); });
```

Then you can also drop the check of InvokeRequired; you can just call it as it is. Works also if you need to pass parameters, so there is no need for other parameter-specific delegates (works just as well with the parameter-less Action delegate as well):

```
private void SetControlText(Control ctl, string text)
{
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { ctl.Text = text; });
}
```

Comment: Why would you create an anonymous delegate just to cast it to an existing delegate type?  You should just use the delegate type directly.

Comment: @Brian: you mean like this: Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { ctl.Text = text; }));  ? As far as I can see that produces the exact same IL code as my code above, so it's down to personal taste, I guess.

Comment: what is the difference between MethodInvoker and Action?
Also, I am checking InvokeRequired because it seems a better practice, eg, faster.

Comment: @Fredrik: Brian meant using new MethodInvokder(Refresh) rather than (MethodInvoker)delegate { Refresh(); }

Comment: if it is the same IL in the end, then I guess it is more about preference, but if the delegate exists I don't understand why you would prefer to use the anonymous syntax.  Just seems more straight forward to just declare it and use it.

Comment: Use Invoke((MethodInvoker)Refresh) or Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Refresh)) instead of Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Refresh(); }) ... the latter creates an additional level of indirection by creating an anonymous method which only calls Refresh(), instead of creating a delegate to Refresh() itself.

Comment: @Purusartha: That sounds strange. Can you provide the code that reproduces that? Would be interesting to see so that I can correct any errors.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I really need an entire delegate
>   dedicated just for this? aren't there
>   any generic delegates at all?

Defining your own delegates can really make debugging easier, if only because Intellisense can tell you the names of your parameters. For example, you write a delegate like this:

```
public delegate int UpdateDelegate(int userID, string city, string, state, string zip);
```

When you use it code, .NET will inform you of the parameter names, delegate name, etc, so there's a lot of context right in the delegate definition if you aren't sure exactly how something is used.

However, if you don't mind sacrificing Intellisense, there is already a class of delegates definined in the System namespace which can be used as ad-hoc delegates:

```
Func<T>
Func<T, U>
Func<T, U, V>
Func<T, U, V, W>
Action, Action<T>
Action<T, U>
Action<T, U, V>
Action<T, U, V, W>
```

Only `Action` and `Action` exist in .NET 2.0, but its easy enough to declare a helper class with the remaining delegates you need for these kind of miscellaneous ad hoc functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are generic delegates.  `Action<T1, T2...>` is a generic delegate that takes some parameters and returns no value, and `Func<T1, T2...R>` is a generic delegate that takes some parameters and returns a value.